# Share sshd_config publicly?

Tags: ssh, security

I have an `sshd_config` file [that I use for my Raspberry Pi](https://gist.github.com/normalocity/6098923), and I think it's pretty well locked down, but I'm curious is it's a bad idea for me to share it publicly like this, and if there is objective value in letting other people see it (e.g. people will tell me that I need to change an option or lock it down even more). I share this one for this question because my RPi is a small/negligible target, and my SSH keys are still secret.

So, essentially I'm asking, good/bad idea to publicly share SSH configs (but not keys, or credentials, obviously)? I think many would argue that the less information you give to a potential attacker the better, but I would hope that sharing it so alternative points of view could comment on it would out weight the risk.

Comment: It does give some information – for example, `AuthorizedKeysFile /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` tells me that *all* accounts on the system can be accessed with the same credentials (SSH keypairs) as your own.

Comment: So using `%h/.ssh/authorized_keys` would be better?

Comment: Yes, or just `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`, since it can be relative to the home directory. ⫽ Aside from that, I would agree with @tapped-out. IMHO, as long as the login credentials and various cryptographic keys are secure, the whole system should remain secure.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not also handing out the IP address or hostname of your server, it's impossible to associate this SSH config with your server.

I see no issue with sharing it publicly.